# What to do with a highly voted answer that is half-wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers

On the question [How do I earn SC2's "Hurry up, it's raid night" achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4487/28182), there is [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4489/28182) which is highly voted (+25/-2), yet noticeably wrong.

The answer makes two separate points:

- How to track time-progress for the achievement, suggesting to go to the 'Load' menu and looking at the file stat 'Duration' for that particular load.
- How to replay missions to lower overall time.

However, as raised in the comments a couple of times - the first part regarding 'Duration' only represents the current level - Even if the player is wandering around the ship talking to people, that counts as a 'level' and has a duration, but is **not** tracked by the achievement progress, and does **not** represent overall playtime. In other words, it's completely wrong.

My question is, **what should we do?** Obviously the answer has been around for a while (coming up 5 years in fact) and I'd be loathe to remove it in its entirety, but I also don't like having misinformation in the *second-highest-voted answer* in one of our more popular questions.

I and others have also left comments to this effect however the OP hasn't bothered to edit it out.

So, should we:

- Edit out the misinformation?
- Flag/Remove the answer?
- Convert to Community Wiki and then edit it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off - don't flag things just because they are incorrect - as noted on another relatively recent meta, there is a decline reason specifically for this case, as flags are not supposed to be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer. (The only real exception to this is when the answer is something that is technically dangerous, like someone throwing in the rm -rf as a suggestion how to solve a problem, or a link to malware, etc. In that case, use the custom reason and give us as much detail as possible so we can deal with it.)

You can create your own, correct answer, and hope the community sees it and upvotes it, or if it is just a matter of slightly inaccurate info, edit it out (but if you're going to functionally change the intent of the entire answer or remove most of it, don't do this - I mean more if it is just a name that is wrong or the like).

Beyond that, downvote, clearly point out in comments where the answer is wrong, write a better answer, and that's really all you can do.

CW is not for cases like this. In fact, it is really something that should be used quite rarely and now can only be done by a mod. It was generally meant for poll style answers or joke style answers, or long, frequently edited lists, none of which are highly desirable anywhere on the network (see this [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question) for more thoughts on when CW is appropriate (hint: almost never)).

It's unfortunate that there is no real recourse for things like this other than using the downvote/commenting skills that you've already used, but [Tim Post's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160456/168476) has some good points about why nuking these things on sight isn't always the best approach.

Comment: Ok, well I've downvoted and commented, so hopefully the OP comes back at some point and cleans up. I don't disagree with what your saying, but I will add that it goes against our mission of "[building a library of detailed answers to every question about videogames and videogame consoles.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)" to leave it out there spreading misinformation like this. I've actually had this happen, [directly at me](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/215452/28182) which is what prompted this question in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that is a little counterintuitive to other statements, so I am glad you brought it up. :)

Comment: This is fairly disappointing. It seems like one of those cases where an answer should be deleted.